# JaxWS : Externalize Http Conduit name Attribute

Tags: web-services, soap, apache-camel, jax-ws, webservices-client

I have the WSDL file for the SOAP webservice that i need to invoke over http. Using cxf wsdl2java plugin i have created the stub methods.

**I have created the webservice client using jaxws. The webservice has basic authentication enabled. I am trying to configure http conduit**

```
 my application.properties
 --------------------------
 webservices.http.auth.username=username
 webservices.http.auth.password=password
 fold.webservices.http.auth.authtype=Basic
 webservices.http.conduit.property.name=https://fixed_deposits-test.co.in/fold-webservices/services.*
 fold.updateservice.soap.address=https://fixed_deposits-test.co.in/fold-webservices/services/UpdateService
 ----------------------------
```

> **My Spring Context...**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:jaxws="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws"
        xmlns:http-conf="http://cxf.apache.org/transports/http/configuration"
        xmlns:sec="http://cxf.apache.org/configuration/security"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                    http://cxf.apache.org/transports/http/configuration http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/configuration/http-conf.xsd
                    http://cxf.apache.org/configuration/security http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/configuration/security.xsd
                    http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxws.xsd">

   <bean id="properties" class="org.apache.camel.spring.spi.BridgePropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
      <property name="locations">
        <util:list>
            <value>file:${config.dir}/application.properties</value>
        </util:list>
      </property>
    <property name="systemPropertiesModeName" value="SYSTEM_PROPERTIES_MODE_OVERRIDE" />
   </bean>

   <jaxws:client id="updateServiceClient" serviceClass="com.fold.facade.v1.UpdateService" address="${fold.updateservice.soap.address}" >
      <jaxws:inInterceptors>
        <bean id="loggingInInterceptor" class="org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingInInterceptor" >
            <property name="prettyLogging" value="true" />
        </bean>
      </jaxws:inInterceptors>
      <jaxws:outInterceptors>
        <bean id="loggingOutInterceptor" class="org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingOutInterceptor" >
            <property name="prettyLogging" value="true" />
        </bean>
      </jaxws:outInterceptors>
   </jaxws:client>

  <http-conf:conduit name="***?????????***">
    <http-conf:authorization>
        <sec:UserName>${fold.webservices.http.auth.username}</sec:UserName>
        <sec:Password>${fold.webservices.http.auth.password}</sec:Password>
        <sec:AuthorizationType>${fold.webservices.http.auth.authtype}</sec:AuthorizationType>
    </http-conf:authorization>
</http-conf:conduit>
```

I have done a lot of searching online so as to what should be the valid value for **name attribute..**

accouring to CXF documentation it should be...

```
{WSDL_endpoint_target_namespace}PortName.http-conduit
```

**my WSDL File has..**

```
...
targetNamespace="http://facade.fold.com/" and
...
<wsdl:port binding="tns:UpdateServiceImplServiceSoapBinding"
        name="UpdateServiceImplPort">
        <soap:address
            location="https://fixed_deposits-test.co.in/fold-webservices/services/UpdateService" />
    </wsdl:port>
```

**so i tried with these..**

```
<http-conf:conduit name="{http://facade.fold.com/}UpdateServiceImplPort.http_conduit">
or
<http-conf:conduit name="*UpdateServiceImplPort.http_conduit">
or
<http-conf:conduit name="{http://facade.fold.com/}*.http_conduit">
```

But none of them work as i get 401 unauthorized exception..

*org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPException: HTTP response '401: Unauthorized' when communicating with https://fixed_deposits-test.co.in/fold-webservices/services/UpdateService*

> ***THERE ARE COUPLE OF WAYS I GOT IT TO WORK***

```
a) <http-conf:conduit name="*.http_conduit">
```

but i really don't want to do it this way...

```
b) <http-conf:conduit name="https://fixed_deposits-test.co.in/fold-webservices/services/UpdateService">
```

this is hardcoding the SOAP service URL... which i don't want as i am looking for externalizing URL as my SOAP URL's are different for different environment..(dev /test /prod etc)

**Below is my best shot at externalization, but it failed with 401 Unauthorized Exception...**

properties were replaced in all other instances in my spring context, but not for http-conf:conduit **name attribute** :(

```
<http-conf:conduit name="${webservices.http.conduit.property.name}">
```

As a workaround i am currently using the regex approach which works..

```
<http-conf:conduit name="*.*/fold-webservices/services/UpdateService">
```

> ***But i really want to figure out if it possible to externalize it and read from properties file. And i want to do it the Spring
>   configuration way. Please help me !!!***

Answer (score 3):

We had the same issue with JBoss Fuse 6.1 (Camel CXF 2.12.0).
You can see what the http-conf:conduit name is set to by enabling DEBUG log level and looking at your log, there should be a log line such as:

```
DEBUG 10:40:41,437 [Camel (cnpms-as-mnp-ctx) thread #0 - JmsConsumer[cnpms-queue]] org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit.setTlsClientParameters(HTTPConduit.java:901) - Conduit '{http://acme.com/manageporting/v1}ManageportingPortPort.http-conduit' has been (re)configured for plain http.
```

So in this case you would set the name as:

```
<http-conf:conduit name="{http://acme.com/manageporting/v1}ManageportingPortPort.http-conduit"
```

But the Web Service (WS) Interface Class is defined as:

```
@WebService(targetNamespace = "http://acme.com/manageporting/v1", name = "ManageportingPort")
@SOAPBinding(parameterStyle = SOAPBinding.ParameterStyle.BARE)
public interface ManageportingPort {
```

Generated from WSDL:

```
<wsdl:portType name="ManageportingPort">
```

Note that by following the [CXF documentation](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/client-http-transport-including-ssl-support.html#ClientHTTPTransport%28includingSSLsupport%29-Theconduitelement) you would expect the port name component to be "ManageportingPort" NOT "ManageportingPortPort" i.e. with "Port" appended to it.
However looking at how the portQName is resolved in org.apache.cxf.jaxws.support.JaxWsImplementorInfo.getEndpointName(), if the port name is not set in the WS Interface Class, and the name is not null or blank, it sets the port name to `portName = name + "Port"` otherwise it sets it to `portName = implementorClass.getSimpleName() + "Port"`.

Comment: +1 for the DEBUG hint. The expected conduit name was not what I was expecting based on my WSDL. Saves you a lot of trial and error.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem...

In my case the following 2 changes helped:

1) add "Port" postfix to the port name, despite it is not defined in the wsdl this was

```
e.g wsdl: 
<wsdl:port name="XXXSoap">
```

will be "XXXSoapPort" in the conduit definition

2) remove the "\" at the end of the target namespace name

==> therefore try

```
<http-conf:conduit name="{http://facade.fold.com}UpdateServiceImplPort.http_conduit">
or 
<http-conf:conduit name="{http://facade.fold.com}UpdateServiceImplPortPort.http_conduit">
```

Answer (score 1):

I came across the same challenge and found no existing solution. Spring doesn't seem to resolve placeholders in bean names (make lots of sense). However, this is a valid case unless cxf allows conduit matching using another attribute.

There are a few ways to solve this problem:

1. Define conduit beans programmatically (lose the neat of xml declaration)
2. Find a way to resolve the bean names which contains placeholders

I prefer option 1 and this is the implementation which I'm happy with. Please note that `PropertyPlaceholderResolver` is our own utility which uses the same defined resolver bean.

```java
public class NameWithPlaceholderBeanFactoryPostProcessor implements BeanFactoryPostProcessor
{
    @Override
    public void postProcessBeanFactory(final ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory) throws BeansException
    {
        if (!(beanFactory instanceof DefaultListableBeanFactory))
            return;

        DefaultListableBeanFactory bf = (DefaultListableBeanFactory) beanFactory;

        String[] names = bf.getBeanDefinitionNames();
        for (String name : names)
        {
            if (name.indexOf('$') < 0)
                continue;

            BeanDefinition bd = bf.getBeanDefinition(name);
            bf.removeBeanDefinition(name);
            bf.registerBeanDefinition(PropertyPlaceholderResolver.resolvePlaceHolders(name), bd);
        }
    }
}
```

The final step is to define this as a spring bean.